# How to force Showoff to not add a margin-top to the .content div

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, rubygems, presentation

Scott Chacon's Showoff gem is a great alternative to Powerpoint/Keynote... but the fact that it always centers content vertically is annoying. Sometimes you want to force content to the top of the slide. Additionally, there seems to be a bug in that incremental content with images isn't considered when calculating margin-top, which results in incremental content ending up off the bottom of the slide.

Is there a way to force Showoff to not add a margin-top value to the .content div? It is done at the element level, so you aren't able to override with css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the patch from [this commit](https://github.com/schacon/showoff/pull/127) along with adding fixed-top to the relevant slides was a suitable workaround.